# When are you supposed to get your complimentary Cartel Points?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I bought the game on 28th of January.  When I activated the game, I got immediately the complimentary 500 Cartel Points.

After that, I entered the Game Time Card I bought in a Store on 26th of February. Since then, I did not get my complimentary Cartel Points for February.

Can anyone tell me when you are supposed to get your complimentary Cartel Points as a subscriber?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I actually got my 500 Cartel Points Sunday Morning, March 2nd my time. So my conclusion is that we get complimentary cartel points on every first on every calender month and not the first of your subscription month. It also seems to be issued on a schedule of the US Timezone, considering the time frame (March 2nd, early morning) I have gotten them.

Comment: `we get complimentary cartel points on every first on every calender month` -- this is definitely not correct.  I get mine mid-month.  It's just within a couple days of your subscription rollover date.

Answer (score 1):

You get your CC a couple days after you started/paid your subscription. I get my CC around the 8th of the month.

After I took a break and resubbed I checked again when I got my CC. Right now i get them around the 22nd of the month.